# Is there a matplotlib counterpart of MATLAB "stem3"?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, stem-plot

In MATLAB, it is quite easy to make a 3d stem plot with the [`stem3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/stem3.html) command.

Is there a similar command in matplotlib? I checked the online documentation for the latest version, but could not find one. Can anyone give some suggestions on how to plot this data as a 3d stem plot?

```py
import numpy as np

N = 50
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
x = np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(theta)
z = range(N)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm unaware of any direct equivalent of `stem3` in matplotlib. However, it isn't hard to draw such figures (at least in its basic form) using [Line3D](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D)s:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

N = 100
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
x = np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(theta)
z = range(N)
for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z):        
    line=art3d.Line3D(*zip((xi, yi, 0), (xi, yi, zi)), marker='o', markevery=(1, 1))
    ax.add_line(line)
ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, N)    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: +1. This looks even nicer than the example on Matlab's page.  Is it possible to have the little balls on top of the lines, too?

Comment: Thanks for providing the impetus to pursue this. At first I thought I'd have to overlay a scatter plot, but it appears setting a [marker](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_marker) and using [set_markevery(2)](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markevery) can also do.

Answer (score 3):

As unutbu's, just with a conventional plot:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = [2,4,1,3]
y = [3,5,6,7]
z = [4,5,6,7]  
for xx,yy,zz in zip(x,y,z): 
    plot([xx,xx], [yy,yy], [0,zz], '-')
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Did you import * from pylab?

Answer (score 1):

#### New in matplotlib 3.4.0

The built-in [`ax.stem`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stem.html) now has native 3D support. Just create 3D axes via `subplot_kw` and pass 3 arrays into [`ax.stem`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stem.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
#                      -------------------------------
ax.stem(x, y, z)
ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z')
```

[image]

---

Note that the stems can be reoriented along any axis:

- `orientation='z'`: stems are rooted in `xy` plane, projected along `z` **(default)**
- `orientation='y'`: stems are rooted in `xz` plane, projected along `y`
- `orientation='x'`: stems are rooted in `yz` plane, projected along `x`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
ax.stem(x, y, z, orientation='x')
#                ---------------
```

[image]